# How to download Udemy Videos?

Tags: video

Once you buy a course there is usually option to download individual lecture. However there are many courses on Udemy which do not have download option for the lecture. Is there a way to download them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To download udemy videos download **udemy-dl** which is a python based application. It helps login and then download all your paid udemy videos which do not even have download option.

Following are steps for Mac:

1. Install pip

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

2. Install udemy-dl

```
sudo pip install udemy-dl
```

Use the following commands to download the course:

```
udemy-dl course-url
```

This is prompt username and password. You can supply it in command itself

```
udemy-dl -u username -p password course-url
```

Many times connection break causes course are really or internet issues. You can specify start and end of lecture number to download specific lecture.

```
udemy-dl -u username -p password --lecture-start 1 --lecture-end 99 course-url
```

Comment: This does not work for me. it only creates the folder structure and downloads only other content like(.html) but not download videos. Here is a cmd which i using   `udemy-dl.exe -u mymail@gmail.com -p mypassword https://www.udemy.com/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate`

Comment: I'm done with all these codes but it is showing me the error "[CRITICAL-407] Cannot download lecture "Program To Generate Fake Employee Data For Database TestingPart-1": "u'view_html'"https://stackoverflow.com/users/936617/pikachu-go
"

Comment: @surenderpal you can download the all udemy course with this library no need to install any language just download and run https://github.com/maabiddevra/udemy-dl/

Comment: @Aabid No, it's not working like that. you can't download the videos like this.

Comment: @surenderpal the package I mention will definitely, let me know if you are facing any error

Answer (score 30):

**The udemy-dl method doesn't always work**; but the ***youtube-dl*** method works every time! And I'm personally using it for downloading Udemy courses all at once (full course) or also individual videos.
You can do so easily with the help of the **`youtube-dl`** Python script.

0. You have to have Python and PIP installed.
1. Open command prompt or terminal
2. Type in there: **`pip install youtube-dl`**
3. Then after downloading **youtube-dl** , open your Udemy account where you have bought the course.
4. Open the course that you want to download.
5. Click on the **course content** option
6. Copy the **link** in **url** bar [copy the **link** in **url** bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRSjD.png)
7. Finally, execute the following command in your terminal:

   C:\Users\ARSHDEEP SINGH>** youtube-dl -u user@gmail.com -p password COURSE_LINK**

*Type your username or e-mail and password*

***If the username and password are correct, the following will appear in your terminal:***

```
[udemy:course] Downloading login popup
[udemy:course] Logging in as 2arshahuja@gmail.com
[udemy:course] python-for-data-science-and-machine-learning-bootcamp: Downloading webpage
[udemy:course] 903744: Downloading course curriculum
[download] Downloading playlist: Python for Data Science and Machine Learning Bootcamp
[udemy:course] playlist Python for Data Science and Machine Learning Bootcamp: Collected 133 video ids (downloading 133 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 133
[udemy] Downloading login popup
[udemy] 5440650: Downloading webpage
[udemy] 5440650: Downloading lecture JSON
[download] Resuming download at byte 114615
[download] Destination: Introduction to the Course-6808420.mp4
[download]   0.7% of 43.01MiB at 66.01KiB/s ETA 11:02
```

[here explained with screenshots!! also explained for mac users](https://github.com/arshahuja/udemy-download-script)

Comment: Can you download also the files attached and subs with this method?

Comment: You may want to add **-o '%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s'** after the password and the link to the course.

`$ youtube-dl -u user -p password -o '%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' course_link`

This will download the Udemy courses keeping each chapter in separate directory.

Comment: not working. it says unauthorozed even though credentials are correct.

Comment: Thank you, this works excellently.

Comment: can confirm this still works in 2019, thankyou

Comment: doesn't work for me 2020

Comment: not working anymore .. there is an official issue/bug filed since Oct 2019 :( 
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/22705

Comment: As of 2023: `ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`. Will check for resolution.